How do i check what values do I have to remove from a list of numbers to make it monotonic? (newest python)
Basically lets say I have a list of 6 integers: 1 1 2 1 1 1
My existing algorithm knows that the list isn't monotonic, and knows that the highest monotonic sub division is 1 1 1.
What it needs to know is that by removing 2 the whole function becomes monotonic.
Now, at first, with 6 characters it will be quite easy, but what if the list consists of 9 integers:
1 2 3 0 0 0 4 5 6
The longest monotonic sub division is 0 4 5 6 (always rising), but if we want to keep that part we would have to remove 5 other integers. Meanwhile, by removing the three zeros in the middle we get a longer monotonic list.
Me and my friends have theorized that if done by brute force it would take hours of work and have so many if clauses that it would classify as an AI program (jk) so does anybody have any idea on how to tackle this issue?
Here's my current code, with comments and a rundown of variables:
#tablica is just a polish word for a board, it's the list of integers we need to test
#max_list is the length of the biggest monotonic subdivision of the list
#current list is the subdivision that the program is currently checking
#type= the type of monotonicity the current subdivision possesses
#ftype = the type of monotonicity the whole list possesses




tablica=[]
for i in range(6):
    n=int(input())
    tablica.append(n)
def mono(tablica):
    current_list=[]
    max_list=[]

    type=0
    ftype=0
    for i in range(-1,len(tablica)):
        print(f'{i+1}:')
        if tablica[i-1] == tablica[i]:
            if type == 0 or type == 1:
                type=1
                current_list.append(tablica[i])


            else:
                ftype= -1
                if len(max_list)<len(current_list):
                    max_list = current_list.copy()

                type=0
                current_list.clear()
                current_list.append(tablica[i])

            print(current_list,max_list)


        elif tablica[i-1] < tablica[i]:
            if type == 0 or type == 2:
                type=2
                current_list.append(tablica[i])


            else:
                ftype= -1
                if len(max_list)<len(current_list):
                    max_list = current_list.copy()


                type=0
                current_list.clear()
                current_list.append(tablica[i])

            print(current_list,max_list)

        elif tablica[i-1] > tablica[i]:
            if type == 0 or type == 3:
                type=3
                current_list.append(tablica[1])

            else:
                ftype= -1
                if len(max_list)<len(current_list):
                    max_list = current_list.copy()

                type=0
                current_list.clear()
                current_list.append(tablica[i])

            print(current_list,max_list)

    if len(max_list) < len(current_list):
        max_list = current_list.copy()
    if ftype==0:
        ftype=type


    return ftype, len(max_list), max_list,
print(mono(tablica))






Also Longest increasing subsequence.

There is a trivial O(n^2) algorithm.  For each element, you keep track of how long is the longest monotonic sequence ending at that element.  Once you. have the first k elements filled in, filling in the k+1st element is just a scan through all previous elements.
There's probably an O(n log n) algorithm.  But this is the first thing that came to me.
